# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp

Tags: jsp, maven

I have an old struts 1 app that has always been built using Ant, which I'm converting to use Maven instead. The structure of my app is modular, with dependency management in the containing module. The containing module's dep mgmt section contains:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        ...
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

When I build the war (I run the `package` Maven job from the containing module) and run a Tomcat configuration with that war from intelliJ, I see the following in my browser:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to load class for JSP
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:161)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:340)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

root cause
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to load class for JSP
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.load(JspCompilationContext.java:630)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:149)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:340)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp
java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:134)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:66)
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.load(JspCompilationContext.java:628)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:149)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:340)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

Everything I can find from searching on this suggests the cause is a version conflict in javax.servlet jars, but there is nothing in my WEB-INF/lib directory at all. I have tried using scope of `provided`, `compile`, and even `install/pom`, but those don't do anything helpful.

There is nothing additional in the tomcat logs.

I confirmed that the jsps are being compiled. I am using jspc-maven-plugin.

In my sub-module's (not the containing one's) pom.xml, I have:

```
<build>
    <!-- default goal to run if somebody doesn't pick one (rarely matters) -->
    <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>

    <!-- resources and filtering - also see configuration under maven-war-plugin below -->
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <filters>
        <filter>src/main/resources/${env}.properties</filter>
        <filter>src/main/resources/${env}.tokens</filter>
    </filters>

    <plugins>
        <!-- begin - precompiling jsps -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jspc-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>jspc</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <warSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webroot</warSourceDirectory>
                        <inputWebXml>${basedir}/src/main/webroot/WEB-INF/web.xml</inputWebXml>
                        <!--<workingDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webroot</workingDirectory>-->
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <!-- end - precompiling jsps -->

        <!-- used to build warfiles -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${pom.basedir}/src/main/webroot</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                        <!--<targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>-->
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I can see in the maven build output that the jsps are being compiled. But I still get the JasperException.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's been a while since I posted this, but I thought I would show how I figured it out (as best as I recall now).

I did a Maven dependency tree to find dependency conflicts, and I removed all conflicts with exclusions in dependencies, e.g.:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Also, I used the `provided` scope for javax.servlet dependencies so as not to introduce an additional conflict with what is provided by Tomcat when I run the app.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

HTH.

Answer (score 17):

An addition to the other answers that didn't work for me: **In my case the error occurred due to permission errors**. The project got deployed while the tomcat was running as root, later when started as tomcat user I got the error from the question title.

Solution in my case was to set the right permissions, e.x. on a unix system:

```
cd <tomcat-dir>
chown -R <tomcat-user> *
```

Answer (score 3):

I have had the same problem in my project. I used an IntelliJ Idea 14 and Maven 8.
And what I've noticed is that when I added a tomcat destination to to IDE it automaticly linked two jars from tomcat lib directory, they were servlet-api and jsp-api. Also I had them in my pom.xml. I killed a whole day trying to figure out why I'm getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp. And [kewpiedoll99](https://stackoverflow.com/users/187423/kewpiedoll99) is right. That is because there are dependency conflicts. When I added provided to those two jars in my pom.xml I found a happiness :)

Answer (score 3):

I had to delete Tomcat's work directory as it had cached previously generated files. To do this:

1. Stop Tomcat
2. Delete the 'work' directory
3. Start Tomcat

This will cause the work directory to be newly generated.

Answer (score 2):

What version of tomcat are you using ? What appears to me is that the tomcat version is not supporting the servlet & jsp versions you're using. You can change to something like below or look into your version of tomcat on what it supports and change the versions accordingly.

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: I'm using 6.0.35, which appears to support Servlet 2.5 and JSP 2.1. I realized that that's a more recent version of jsp-api than I was including, so I upgraded mine to 2.2, the most recent. I also did a mvn dependency tree and made sure that no conflicting versions are being included by dependencies. Still no dice. Even using `provided` as you suggested does not fix it.

Comment: Are you performing a clean build/run ? What version of maven are you using ? Also, that jsp-maven plugin you're using, that's not at all required. I believe you're using maven 2.x

Comment: I'm doing clean builds; I'm clearing IntelliJ's caches periodically. I'm using Apache Maven 3.1.1 - and yeah, I moved that jsp precompilation to the prod profile, realizing belatedly that I don't need (or want) that for dev. Frankly it was a grasp at a straw ('maybe I need to precompile?') before I realized I knew better. I'm still stuck, so if you think of anything else I'd love to hear it. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

I also lost a half of day trying to fix this.

It appeared that root was my project pom.xml file with dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Other members of the team had no problems.
At the end it appeared, that I got newer tomcat which has different version of jsp-api provided (in tomcat 7.0.60 and above it will be jsp-api 2.2).

So in this case, options would be:

```
a) installing different (older/newer) tomcat like (Exactly what I did, because team is on older version)
b) changing dependency scope to 'compile'
c) update whole project dependencies to the actual version of Tomcat/lib provided APIs
d) put matching version of the jsp-api.jar in {tomcat folder}/lib
```

Answer (score 0):

This was caused because of something like this in my case:

```
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <include-prelude>/headerfooter/header.jsp</include-prelude>
        <include-coda>/headerfooter/footer.jsp</include-coda>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

The problem was actually I did not have header.jsp in my project. However the error message was still saying index_jsp was not found.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem is fixed by setting the right permissions for the tomcat home path:

```
cd /opt/apache-tomee-webprofile-7.1.0/
chown -R tomcat:tomcat *
```

Answer (score 0):

I my case I'd manually moved a .war file to /var/lib/tomcat9/webapps
and unzipped it, then did "chown -R tomcat:tomcat *" in that directory and it resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

I add `standard` dependency，it works

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
    <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```