# Can't get JSTL to work with Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, jstl

I can't seem to get JSTL working with my current installation. I recently started fiddling around with Spring MVC, learning as I'm trying stuff. It was great until I got to using JSTL, which I can't seem to get it right.

The error I get is

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.HelloWorld_jsp
```

My HelloWorld.jsp file:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Posts</title>
</head>
<body>
<c:foreach var="post" items="${listPosts}" varStatus="status">
    ${status.index + 1} ${post.title}<br />
</c:foreach>
</body>
</html>
```

And in case you need them, my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>HelloWorld</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

</project>
```

And web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I have the CLASSPATH environment variable set up properly (to the lib folder of tomcat) and I tried putting jstl-1.2.jar in the WEB-INF/lib folder as well as trying to declare dependencies several times in pom.xml (doing things I googled, not sure how correct they are). Nothing worked so far.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index\_jsp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19963052/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-apache-jsp-index-jsp)

Comment: Well no matter what, you need to put the jstl dependancy in there. It maybe a problem that there are some version mixups

Comment: For starters, when getting an exception which you don't understand, always include the **entire** stack trace which you can find in server log. For mediors who understand exceptions, just the bottommost root cause of the stack trace is sufficient as it is the part which represents the entire answer at its own.

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely the problem is missing dependencies in your pom.xml.

SUGGESTIONS:

- Look at this tutorial:

  [Spring MVC and List Example (mkyong)](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-and-list-example/)
- Then look at the troubleshooting tips in this link:

  [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19963052/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-apache-jsp-index-jsp)

Please post back what you find!