# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException Error in Maven Project

Tags: java, maven, jsp

i made a JSP Project with Tomcat 8.5.11 (maven project) but when I run the page, i get an ClassnotFoundExcption.

I have dao, controllers, service,model layer in my project.

MY error

```
 HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp

type Exception report

message java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:176)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:380)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp
    java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:129)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:60)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:171)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:380)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.5.11 logs.
```

And it's my index.jsp pages.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Department Management</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Department Data</h1>
<form:form action="department.do" method="POST" commandName="Department">

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>DepartmentID</td>
            <td><form:input path="DEPARTMENT_ID" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Department Name</td>
            <td><form:input path="DEPARTMENT_NAME" /></td>
        </tr>

        <td colspan="2">

            <input type="submit" name="action" value="Add" />
            <input type="submit" name="action" value="Edit" />
            <input type="submit" name="action" value="Delete" />
            <input type="submit" name="action" value="Search" />

        </td>

    </table>

    <table border="1">
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>NAME</th>
        <c:forEach items="${departmentList}" var="Department">
            <tr>
                <td>${department.departmentID}</td>
                <td>${department.departmentName}</td>
            </tr>

        </c:forEach>
    </table>


</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>toyota-travel</groupId>
<artifactId>toyota-travel</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>toyota-travel Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
                <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Spring Security -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Security -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-xc</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20090211</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>toyota-route</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9.2.2.v20140723</version>
            <configuration>
                <webApp>
                    <contextPath>/toyota-route/</contextPath>
                </webApp>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Showing your POM file would be helpful.

Comment: Did you include a jasper jar in your war file?  This sounds like a conflict between jar files supplied by Tomcat and jar files in your war.  I would remove any conflicting jars from the war.

Comment: @luc14n0 added pom.xml

Comment: Servlet API should be marked as provided, no?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index\_jsp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19963052/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-apache-jsp-index-jsp)

Comment: This is often fixed by adding tomcat 8.5.11 (your current version) servlet-api and jsp-api to the POM (as provided) so it can be used to evict older versions since a lot of libraries use it as a dependency and will conflict.  Look in your tomcat catalina.out and see if it complains about the conflict since you should never include servlet-api in a WAR deployed to tomcat, it's a library provided by the tomcat container.

Comment: i tried but not working @KarthikeyanVaithilingam

Comment: how to i include jasper jar?My tomcat configuration Deployment just have project folder.İf i adding the war file, tomcat is not working

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of a ClassNotFoundException is usually a missing (or out-of-date) Maven dependency.

I suggest to add more jsp dependencies. This is what I use on Tomcat 8:

```
  <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Dominique Ubersfeld